# Firebase: how to add auto-generated document id to the document in svelte?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, svelte

What is the right way to add a firebase document with an auto-generated id in svelte?

So far I am using the following code snippet:

```
db.collection('colname').add({ id:'temp', text:'sometext' }).then(
    result=>{
        db.collection('colname').doc(result.id).update({id: result.id});
    }
);
```

What I don't like about this solution:

1. There are 2 separate interactions with database;
2. Svelte renders the content 2 times, i.e. after each database interaction. This is also the reason why I need to add a temporary id in add().

Is there any neater solution?

---

**Context**:

I want to pass the document as a parameter to a svelte SvelteSubComponent:

```
let docs = [];
db.collection('colname').onSnapshot(data =>{
    docs=data.docs;    
});

(...)

{#each docs as doc}
<SvelteSubComponent {...doc.data()}/>
{/each}
```

I want to be able to access the document id in the SvelteSubComponent.

Comment: Do you *need* the document id to be the one generated by Firebase, or can it be any unique, randomly generated id?

Comment: @ThomasHennes I guess I don't really need the id to be generated specifically by Firebase. However I want to be sure that the id is _unique_, and that I can easily get the document by its id (i.e. something like db.collection('colname').doc('docId') )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply need a unique, random ID I'd recommend using [the UUID library](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid) (`npm install uuid`) and specifically [UUID v4](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#uuidv4options-buffer-offset).

Then you would use it as follows:

```js
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
...
db.collection('colname').add({ id: uuidv4(), text:'sometext' }).then(...);
```

The generated ID will be a unique randomly generated string of the form `'1b9d6bcd-bbfd-4b2d-9b5d-ab8dfbbd4bed'`.

Answer (score 0):

The `add()` method will generate a random document ID every time. If you want to add the document ID in the document data as well then it'll be best to generate the ID beforehand and then using `set()` to create a document with that ID:

```
const docId = db.collection('colname').doc().id

db.collection('colname').doc(docId).set({ id: docId, text:'sometext' }).then(() => {
  console.log("Document added")
})
```